# Is this readable, if not what should I change?

Tags: javascript, formatting, indentation

I consistenly get comments that my code  is un-readable...I've updated my style to below...any suggestions for improvement?

```
/*
Check - Checks the user input text against regular expressions
*/

// Regular expressions

var patterns = 
  {   
  name: /^[a-zA-Z-\s]{1,20}$/,                              // checks full name
  email: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$/, // checks for valid email form
  pass: /.{6,40}/,                                          // checks for password length
  url:  /^[-\w&:\/\.=\?,#+]{1,}$/,                          // checks for valid url form
  aml:  /<(.+)_([a-z]){1}>$/                                // checks for aml form
  };

function check_item(reg1,text,id,res)
  {
  if(!reg1.exec(text.value))
    {
    o2(id,res);
    return 0;
    }
  return 1;
  }

function check_aml(text)
  {  
  if(a=patterns.aml.exec(text))
    {
    if(a[2]=='p')
      {
      return 0;
      }
    else if (a[2]=='f')
      {
      return 1;
      }
    }
  else
    {
    return 2;
    }
  }

// checks for empty text

function check_empty(text,id,res) 
  {
  for(var d=0;d<text.length;d++)
    {
    if(text[d].value=='')
      {
      o2(id,res);
      return 0;
      }
    }
  return 1;
  }

// checks if two text entries are the same

function check_same(text1,text2,id,res)
  {
  if((text1.value)!=(text2.value))
    {
    o2(id,res);return 0;
    }
  o2(id,'');
  return 1;
  }
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ But yeah, I find that annoying to read.

Comment: JavaScript Patterns by Stoyan Stefanov http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do and / or Crockford's the Good Parts http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do may be a good start.

Comment: Around here lots of folks do opening `{` on the same line as the `function`, `for, or `if` keyword, then make the closing `}` on the same indent as the keyword. Also, lots of folks have moved to a 4-space indent. That said, go with what works for your *community of developers*.

Comment: Readability is also subjective. Personally I don't like the braces on the next line after `function`, `if` or `else`. It makes it harder for *me* to read. But you definitely give your variables and function more meaningful names. E.g. what is `res` or `o2`?

Comment: Your curly brace indention makes me want to punch bunnies.

Comment: Why do people not like symmetry in the {}...I don't undertand it...I think this is the "base case" as to why I write un-readable code...I like symmetry..but I don't think I've ever seen someone else do this...it makes it easy to check for errors + symmetry should be more pleasing to the eye.  Boggles my mind

Comment: I like symmetry... it's the C style. The asymmetric style is usually used in Java.

Comment: @ChrisAaker, no accounting for style. Why do people like country music? :)

Comment: there are concepts...golden ratio, symmetry, etc. that should be universal

Comment: If by "symmetry in the {}" you mean putting both the opening and closing curly braces on their own lines and horizontally aligned with each other then that's fine but I _really_ dislike the way you indent them. A matter of taste, of course, but I'm used to seeing them lined up with the if/for/while/etc of the line before - much more common in JavaScript, Java and C#.

Comment: P.S. For an object literal in a return statement - like `return { key:"value" };` - you _must_ put the opening `{` on the same line as `return` or it doesn't work. You can start a new line after the opening `{` if you like.

Comment: I agree that all things being equal symmetry would be better - but you need to bear in mind that it creates an extra line of whitespace which contains just a brace, compared to putting it on a previous line.  This means less code on a screen (which roughly implies harder to read), and makes it more difficult to noticeably break up distinct "bits" of code with newlines (when there's more newlines within the same bit of code, it doesn't stand out as much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion (foolishly subjective):

```
/*
Check - Checks the user input text against regular expressions
*/

// Regular expressions

var patterns = {   
    name: /^[a-zA-Z-\s]{1,20}$/,                              // checks full name
    email: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$/, // checks for valid email form
    pass: /.{6,40}/,                                          // checks for password length
    url:  /^[-\w&:\/\.=\?,#+]{1,}$/,                          // checks for valid url form
    aml:  /<(.+)_([a-z]){1}>$/                                // checks for aml form
};

function check_item(reg1, text, id, res) {
    if(!reg1.exec(text.value)) {
        o2(id,res);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

function check_aml(text) {  
    if(a = patterns.aml.exec(text)) {
        if(a[2] == 'p') {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (a[2] == 'f') {
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

// checks for empty text

function check_empty(text, id, res) {
    for(var d = 0; d < text.length; d++) {
        if(text[d].value == '') {
            o2(id, res);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// checks if two text entries are the same

function check_same(text1, text2, id, res) {
    if((text1.value) != text2.value) {
        o2(id, res);
        return 0;
    }
    o2(id, '');
    return 1;
}
```

While this reflects my personal preference for javascript code indentation, it doesn't mean that it will improve crappy code. And, yeah, that's crappy code. It's soooo much unreadable with variable names like a, o2, text, ...

I mean you wrote `if(a = patterns.aml.exec(text))`. Do you know the difference between `=`, `==` and `===` in javascript?

For me a code is readable when someone that hasn't written this code (like me) is looking at it and immediately knows what this code does. I must confess that this is not the case with your code. I have to actually think and waste time understanding the meaning of it.

Comment: Thank you.  Why don't you like symmetry in your {} marks as I have written...plus it makes it easier to check for errors?  Just curious?

Comment: @ChrisAaker, each programming language has its commonly accepted conventions. Javascript is no different. And people that are accustomed to those conventions (and usually they are the majority) when reading source code in this given language prefer it to follow those conventions. Look for example at the [source of the jQuery framework](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js). It's even more drastic as it puts spaces between parenthesis. So that is to say that if you don't follow conventions you fall out of the equation and the source code you are writing is considered *readable* by you only.

Comment: yes...this is the response I get...reading a style guide is like reading a dictionary...and doing it for each language is like reaidng multiple dictionaries in mutliple languages...but yes I will do this....or have someone do it once I am done with fixing the naming issues and other...thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the javascript conventions are, but maybe the statements inside curly braces should be indented to the right with respect to the braces themselves. Also, I think you should not right indent the curly braces when you open and close a block, they should be aligned to the first character of the "for" or "function". This works for me.

```
function check_empty(text,id,res) 
{
   for(var d=0;d<text.length;d++)
   {
      if(text[d].value=='')
      {
         o2(id,res);
         return 0;
      }
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Depends what the people who read your code find readable I guess...

Comment: This is closest to the style I prefer...but I like to think of a function as a "heading" and therefore indent the next line like you would to in a document..odd as it may seem

Comment: +1 as it's neat and close to the OP's original.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone says, this is really subjective, but here are a few suggestions:

- Put a space between `if` and `for` and their respective opening parentheses: `if (test)` - this helps to visually differentiate them from function calls.
- I prefer braces on the same line as the statement (`function`, `if`, etc) opening the brace. But that's just taste.
- Most Javascript programmers don't use the structure `if (a = b.exec(text))`, I think because it's so easily confused with `if (a == b.exec(text))`. The one exception I've seen is with regex, though: `while (a = b.exec(text))` - this is a good way to cycle through pattern matches.
- I don't like numeric return values. By preference, I'd either return `true`/`false` or, if you really need other states, return an object with a state and a reason: `return { success: false, message: "Enter a valid email"};`
- Unless there's a need to be more specific, I find that evaluating falsy values is more legible as `if (text[d].value)` than `if (text[d].value == '')` (which is the same thing). If you need type-aware comparison, use `===`.
- As a rule, I stay away from single-letter variables except as iteration counters and the like. If you're minifying/compressing your code before sending it to the client (and usually you should), then there's no disadvantage to using longer, human-readable names.
- Unless there's a really good formatting reason, don't have two statements on one line like `o2(id,res);return 0;`.
- This is as much code optimization as style, but you get better code compression, and probably more readable code, using multiple variable for your regex patterns (e.g. `patternName`, `patternEmail`, etc), rather than putting them all in an object. In general, unless you're going to need to look things up by string key or have some other reason to use an object, simple variables are probably better - see the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) for an excellent example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take, with some internal comments regarding naming conventions.

```
function check_item(reg1, text, id, res) {
    if (req1.exec(text.value)) {
        return 1;
    }

    o2(id, res);
    return 0;
}

function check_aml(text) {
    var a = patterns.aml.exec(text);
    if (!a) {
        return 2;
    }

    if (a[2] == 'p') {
        return 0;
    }

    if (a[2] == 'f') {
        return 1;
    }

    // Else what?
}

// This function is named funky, because
// it does more than check to see if the
// text is empty, it also does something
// with the o2 function.
//
// Why does it not return true/false?
function check_empty(text, id, res) {
    for (var d = 0; d < text.length; d++) {
        if (text[d].value == '') {
            o2(id, res);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

// This function is named funky, because it does
// more than checks to see if they're the same,
// it also does something with the o2 function.
//
// Why does it not return true/false?
function check_same(text1, text2, id, res) {
    if (text1.value != text2.value) {
        o2(id, res);
        return 0;
    }

    o2(id, '');
    return 1;
}
```